# Eloquent Model with dynamic table..?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've got a generic model called `Item` and a related model called `Itemproperties`.

Item -> hasOne -> Itemproperties

Itemproperties -> belongsTo -> Item

The `Item` model has a property called 'itemtype_id' which tells the model which table to store to. Ex: itemtype = 1, then table is itemproperties_1 for itemtype = 2, then table is itemproperties_2.

So I changed the getTable() method on the Itemproperties model:

```
function getTable(){
    return 'item_properties_' . $this->itemtype_id;
}
```

So, when creating a new item and its properties, I've been setting up the Itemproperties like this:

```
// Create & Save the Item
$item = new Item(['itemtype_id' => $itemtype_id]);
$item->save();

// Save the Properties
$itemProperties = new ItemProperties($properties);
$itemProperties->itemtype_id = $item->itemtype_id;
$item->properties()->save($itemProperties);
```

This seems to work fine... when saving the Itemproperties.

However, when I try to retrieve them, by doing `$item->properties`, I don't have a way to tell it the itemtype_id, so it can't find the correct table.

My question: 
**Is there a way to set up the eloquent relationship so that I can pass the item->itemtype_id to the Itemproperties so it knows which table to use?**

Or is there a better overall strategy to accomplish what I'm doing using different tables for different item types?

Comment: Okay based on the last question, the first thing that came to my mind is `morph` i.e polymorphic relationship have you considered this before? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations In anyway you can use this feature?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @OmisakinOluwatobi.  I don't think that would be a good fit for what I'm doing because I'm going have many different types of items and each one will have a different number and combination of columns.

Comment: so if I get you right, you mean the columns in one property differ from the columns in another. say property a has, Z and Y columns, property b can have Z, Y, and K columns?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't really need multiple tables to solve this. Having a relationship between Item and Properties should be sufficient. This means in `Item` model, you should already specify the column to use when building the relationship with `Property`

```
public function property()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Property::class, 'itemtype_id', 'itemtype_id')
}
```

This means the itemtype_id is in the `items` table, and the assumption here is that itemtype_id in Property model is unique (one - to - one)

Then when you have to save a new properties:

```
$item = new Item(['itemtype_id' => $itemtype_id]);
$item->save();
//then saving properties
$item->property()->save($properties); //assuming you already have $properties.
```

The `itemtype_id` is already passed when building the query and it references. This means if you want to retrieve the properties you just incase you find an item with its type id:

```
$item = Item::where('itemtype_id', 1)->first();
//get the properties
$properties = $item->property;
//or simply get the properties by calling the Property model directly:
Property::where('item_property', 1)->first();
```

The only **ways** I might be wrong is if the fields in your different properties varies and/or I completely misunderstood the question, but generally you don't need multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks again for your efforts.  You are right that there is a one to one relationship between Item and Properties, but in my case, each item type  can have vastly different properties.  Ex: Item #1 could be a Customer record with fields: company_name, contact_name, contact_phone; while Item #2 could be a sales opportunity with fields: description, value, followup_date.  I need all items to have a record in the Items table, but the properties need to be stored in different tables because of the differences in their fields / columns.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @BizzyBob did you find the solution?